# Setting and getting the version of the Android Library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I have created a library in Android Studio and wanted to give it to someone for testing.Besides maintaining it in the svn I am providing the version of the library hardcoded in the Library code which I keep on changing everytime I build and send it for testing to track the record.
The code is as below :

```
defaultConfig {
        ..
        ..
        ..
        versionName "0.00.0012"

}
```

and then getting the version of the Library as BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME

Does the App version will change in the AndroidManifest.xml as well automatically? 
is there any other way of managing the various lib versions?

android:versionName="not the same version"

Comment: `Build.gradle` override version defined in `manifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

> Does the App version will change in the AndroidManifest.xml as well automatically?

No, library version will not influence application's version in any way. Both are separate.

> is there any other way of managing the various lib versions?

What you do lets the consumer check the version of the library in code, which is fine. If you want to actually distribute new versions of the library then you'd probably want to use a maven repository - either local or a remote one, and push your library there with given version. This is the version you then reference in `compile 'com.my.library:library:1.2.3'`.

Comment: Its a propriety library and I don't want to push it anywhere but to the customer for the time being. What I want is the app developer can fetch the version of the Library being used internally.  Ican implement get API in the library to return the library version but I want a standard way (if any) via which Android App developer can fetch the library version and for that I wanted to know if there is any convention in the build.gradle or any other file?

Comment: Then the client can import `your.library.package.BuildConfig` and get the `versionCode` from there, no?